# Jquery code not executing in Rails 3 Project

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am setting up a jquery+rails application. There seems to be no problem with including jquery. The source file finally generated finally looks like --->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CodeAliker</title>
        <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="EIklYq2jXM/BSsN+M0V5x9GoFA+WjwYuD0kuLBkjIUg=" name="csrf-token" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <script src="/assets/dashboard.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/assets/dashboard.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="topbar">
    <div class="fill">
          <div class="container">
            <a class="brand" href="#">CodeAliker</a>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active" name='useritem'>
                    <a href="#user" >+myth</a>
                </li>
                <li name='dashitem'>
                    <a href="#panel">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav secondary">
                    <a href="/getout">SignOut</a>
                <li>
            </ul>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="bodydiv">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="sidebar">
              <table class="bordered-table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>BATCH List</th> 
                  </tr>
                </thead>                        
                <tbody id='table-body'>
                  <tr>
                    <td><a href="#">samplebatch</a></th>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>    
            </table>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
               ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


    </body>
</html>
```

My Jquery code in a file dashboard.js looks like -->

```
$('ul.nav li').each(function(){
    console.log('Iterating');
});

$('a').bind('click', function() {  
    alert('Unobtrusive!');  
});
```

The code never executes ,why? However inserting a simple console.log() on the dashscript.js prints!

Comment: Why did you put one `script` and `link` in `body`? Put everything in the `head` only. And try.

Comment: It is controller specific scripts and not application wide scripts so I had included them in my 'dashboard.html.erb' file. The generated code has not put it in head. :|

Comment: Did dashboard.js is getting downloaded? You can check in fiddler. Also you have put query string for refreshing the script, try incrementing it to body=2. You might have updated the script and your browser has cached old version.

Comment: Anyways I fixed this issue by including controller_name in the application.html.erb but it is still not working! :|

Comment: Check the jsFiddle in my answer. It is working.

Comment: "not working" means what? You are logging to console. In chrome, press f12 and go to console tab to see the log.

Comment: There is no log = Not working. Sorry for abstract language.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7409/discussion-between-amar-palsapure-and-myth17)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have put your code in jsFiddle.net and it works : http://jsfiddle.net/kskHX/2/

There might be issue like

- Your `dashboard.js` is not getting downloaded, might be the url is incorrect or invalid. Check in fiddler, firebug, or console of chrome for errors.
- Your browser has cached the js file, and the updated file is not getting downloaded. Change your query string for the js and try again.

**Solution**

The `dashboard.js` was getting downloaded but the functions were not getting executed , asked to shift code to `$(document).ready(` and it worked.

Hope this info helps you.

Comment: Its something else, the dashboard.js is getting downloaded. Also I cleared browser cache and tried it all over again. :|

Comment: Yup! Works flawless now. Thank you for the help! :)